# AWS Codebuild running shell script

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-codebuild

I have a .NetCore based Lambda Project, that I want to build with AWS CodeBuild.

I have a CodeCommit Repo for the source, and I am using a Lambda to trigger build whenever there is a commit to my master branch. I do not want to use CodePipeline. 
I the code build I will be doing following -

1. Build
2. Package
3. Upload package to S3
4. Run some AWS CLI commands to update the lambda function

Now I have a couple of shell scripts that I want to execute as part of this, these scripts are working fine for me locally and that is the reason I want to use them with CodeBuild.

I am using a Ubuntu based .net core image from AWS for my build and nn my code build project, I have updated the build spec to do - `chmod +x *.sh` in pre_build and made other changes to my buildspec.yml as per this thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=760031 and also looked at following blog post trying to do something similar -  http://openbedrock.blogspot.in/2017/03/aws-codebuild-howto.html

This is one such script that I want to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
ZIPFILENAME=""

usage() 
{
    echo "build and package lambda project"
    echo "./build-package.sh "
    echo "Get this help message : -h --help "
    echo "Required Parameters: "
    echo "--zip-filename=<ZIP_FILE_NAME>"
    echo ""
}

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
      usage
      exit 1
fi

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    PARAM=`echo $1 | awk -F= '{print $1}'`
    VALUE=`echo $1 | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
    case $PARAM in
        -h | --help)
            usage
            exit
            ;;
        --zip-filename)
            ZIPFILENAME=$VALUE
            ;;
        *)
            echo "ERROR: unknown parameter \"$PARAM\""
            usage
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Now, I am getting error trying to execute shell command in Code Build:
Running command:

```
sh lambda-deployer.sh --existing-lambda=n --update-lambda=y 
lamdbda-deployer.sh: 5: lambda-deployer.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: can you change usage() to usage () { all on one line, please watch the spaces.

Comment: Thanks, @jarnohenneman - got past that error, there are few others, working to resolve them.

Comment: Just out of curiosity why don't you want to use code pipeline?

Comment: a couple of reasons - 1) Lambda versioning for individual lambda, 2) we will be making updates to our Lambda functions throughout the year, and maybe just once or twice to things like API Gateway. 

CP seems to be doing Create/Replace entire stack, what if we just updated one or two components.